# Execute Batch files preloaded in memory

Tags: batch-file

I seem to have an edge case problem running batch files.  I have discovered that if I run a batch file like below (best shows the issue):

```
ping localhost -n 10 >NUL
echo "HI" > test.txt
```

And during the time when the pings are looping, I delete the batch file, "test.txt" does not get created.  I would have assumed windows would lock the batch file or preload it in memory but it seems to do neither.

I tried `cmd /c test.bat` but that also suffers from this issue and results in "The batch file was not found" when trying to read the next line after ping.

This is an edge case for my project where the batch file was overwritten early and then deleted before the original code finished but just curious if I have any easy options to fix this.

Comment: One command line/block is parsed and run, once completed the next command line/block is parsed and run, etc.

Comment: In the example you've submitted however, you could run `ping.exe` as a seperate process whilst continuing with the `echo` command by using `Start "PingDelay" %SystemRoot%\System32\PING.EXE LocalHost -n 10 1>NUL`, although I'd prefer `Start "TimeoutDelay" %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 9 1>NUL`

Comment: I should have added to the original text, assume these need to be run sequentially and not in parallel.  Is there any syntax to place both lines of commands in a "sequential block" and have them parsed and run in memory one after the other and survive original batch file deletion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it this way:

```
(
ping localhost -n 10 >NUL
echo "HI" > test.txt
goto :EOF
)
```

That is, add a `goto :EOF` command at the end, so the execution of the (deleted) Batch file ends there, and enclose *all commands* in parentheses, so that they all are "preloaded in memory" and executed even if the Batch file is deleted in the meantime...

Comment: Are there a limits on how much code can put within the  parenthesized block?

Comment: @Compo that is a qood question.  I wonder if it would cutoff at 8192 bytes.

Comment: Thank you.  This was the trick!  I also noticed after discussion with a colleague last night that Powershell is mostly compatible with DOS commands and also has the modern ability to read the entire script into memory at launch and doesn't suffer this problem.

Comment: @Compo: As far as I know, there is no limit in the size of code enclosed in parentheses. I reviewed some of the _very large_ programs I wrote. My [Tetris animated game](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6936&p=46206#p46206) have a `for` loop with 6,808 bytes. My [TextToHTML.bat Web page creator](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5016) have a loop comprised of 12,712 bytes. However, the winner is my [VIBORAS.bat animated game](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8606) that have a loop with 27,079 bytes!  **`;)`**